# Comparing strings using strcmp() in qsort

Tags: c, string, strcmp, qsort

I'm currently sorting the `count` fields of the `obj` elements in the `objArray` in `descending order` as you can see in the program below but i also want my program to check if the two current `objA.count` and `objB.count` fields that are being used in the `cmpfunc()` are equal, then check if the `objb.word` string is greater than the `objA.word` string, and if so swap them. However, using the `input.txt` file that i've included below you can see in the output that something's not working.Can you help me figure out what that is? The logic seems right to me but maybe i've missunderstood something in how the `cmpfunc()` works or which string is "bigger".

Program.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* PREPROCESSOR */
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 512 /* each line in the file can have up to 512 chars */

/* Function Declarations */
void sortedCount(int,char **);
void *malloc_or_end(size_t);


/* Function Definitions */

/**
 * Allocates sz bytes of memory using malloc, checks if
 * the memory allocation was successfull and return a void* to the
 * beginning of the allocated memory.
 * */
void* malloc_or_end(size_t sz) {
  void *pointer;
  pointer = malloc(sz);
  if(pointer == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memory, terminating.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  return pointer;
}

/**
 * Function count: Prints the number of times
 * that the selected word is found inside the N first words
 * of the file.
 * */
int count(int N, char *word, int callID,char **wordList) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(strcmp(word,wordList[i]) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(callID == 0) { /* if callID == 0 (main called count and we want the output) */
        printf("%d",count);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return count;
}

typedef struct wordAndCount {
    int count;
    char *word;
} obj;

int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
    obj objA = *(obj *)a;
    obj objB = *(obj *)b;
    int res = objA.count - objB.count;

    if(res > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(res < 0) { /* 2nd count is greater than the first */
        return 2;
    } else {
        int cmpResult = strcmp(objB.word,objA.word);
        if(cmpResult > 0) {
        } else if(cmpResult < 0) {
            /* do nothing */
            char *temp = malloc_or_end(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(temp,objA.word);
            strcpy(objA.word,objB.word);
            strcpy(objB.word,temp);
            free(temp);
        } else {
            /* do nothing */
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

void sortedCount(int N,char **wordList) {
    int i,j = 0;
    int *occurrences;
    obj *objArray;

    /* mem allocation */
    objArray = malloc_or_end(N * sizeof(obj));
    occurrences = malloc_or_end(N * sizeof(int));

    /* initialize occurrences for the "each word is unique and occurs only once" scenario */
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        objArray[i].word = malloc_or_end(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        occurrences[i] = 1;
    }

    determineUniqueWords(occurrences,wordList,N);

    /* populate the wordCounts & uniqueWords "arrays" with the appropriate data in order to sort them successfully */
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(occurrences[i] > 0) {
            objArray[i].count = count(N,wordList[i],1,wordList);
            strcpy(objArray[i].word,wordList[i]);
        }
    }

    /* sort */
    qsort(objArray,N,sizeof(obj),cmpfunc);

    for(i = 0; i< N; i++) {
        if(objArray[i].count == 0 || (strcmp(objArray[i].word,"") == 0)) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d %s\n",objArray[i].count,objArray[i].word);
    }

    /* mem free */
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(objArray[i].word);
    }
    free(objArray);
    free(occurrences);
    return;
}

/* Stelios Papamichail AM 4020 */
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) { /* argv[1] = op argv[2] = name argv[3] = <word> */
    int N = -1;
    int i = 0;
    int spaceNum,nlNum = -1;

    FILE *file; 
    char **wordList; 


    file = fopen(argv[2],"r");

    if(file == (FILE *) NULL) { /* check if the file opened successfully */
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open file\n");
    }

    fscanf(file,"%d",&N); /* get the N number */

    wordList = malloc_or_end(N * sizeof(char *)); /* allocate memory for pointers */

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        wordList[i] = malloc_or_end(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char)); /* allocate memory for strings */
    }

    populateWordsArray(N,wordList,file);

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"-reverse") == 0) {
        reverse(N,wordList);
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-first") == 0) {
        first(N,wordList);
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-middle") == 0) {
        middle(N,wordList);
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-last") == 0) {
        last(N,wordList);
    } else if((strcmp(argv[1],"-count") == 0) && argv[3] != NULL) {
        i = count(N,argv[3],0,wordList);
    } else if((strcmp(argv[1],"-sorted") == 0) && (strcmp(argv[3],"-count") == 0)) {
        sortedCount(N,wordList);
    } else {
        /* i only wish i could print something here */
    }


    /* End of program operations */
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(wordList[i]);
    }
    free(wordList);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Input.txt:

```
11 this is a simple text is a a z z z
```

Output:

```
3 a
3 z
2 is
1 simple
1 text
1 this
```

Expected output:

```
3 z
3 a
2 is
1 simple
1 this
1 text
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, is it all needed for the question? Don't forget the *minimal* in a [***Minimal***, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's actually not but whenever i've posted just part of the full code, i'm always asked to include even the uneeded bits. Should i remove anything uneccessary?

Comment: An MCVE is the minimal code needed to replicate the problem you're asking about. For example, is the argument-handling needed to replicate the problem? Can the data be hardcoded into the program so we don't need all the dynamic bits or the file-handling?

Comment: Your comparison function is not supposed to modify the objects it is comparing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i removed anything i considered to be unccessary for the understanding of the problem, hope this suffices.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is that causing an error/undefined behavior or is it not a best practice principal?

Comment: If the first comparison is equal, return the result of the second one. Don’t modify the contents, there’s no need for that. Let the sort algorithm do the swaps.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you mean `return 2;` ? I'm trying to modify the contents of the `objX.word` strings not the actual vars that are being sorted. Is that an issue?

Comment: No, return what the second comparison returns, being strcmp. That will tell the sort algorithm what to do and will never break anything. Doing manual modifications may break things if the algorithm assumes the data doesn’t change, which is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: What's the purpose of messing around with the `word` fields in your local copies of `objA` and `objB`? They are gone after you return from that function.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i'm trying that but it still doesn't correct the output. How does me returning the result of strcmp when the two `counts` are equal tell qsort how to swap the `word` fields of the `objA` and `objB` fields? I mean isn't qsort supposed to just sort the `count` fields in the way specified by the if statements? Does it even know that i want to swap string values when the `count` of both objects is equal and the 2nd's string value is greater than the firsts? Sorry if i'm saying stupid stuff here, i'm just having a hard time understanding

Comment: @Gerhardh so any changes made to their values won't be applied to each `obj struct` when the `cmpfunc()` returns?

Comment: I just realized that it depends on the type of `word`. If it is `char[]` than the change is lost afterwards. If it is `char*` then the change will persist. But that is not what a compare function is expected to do. Just return -1, 0 or 1 and let `qsort` do the rest

Comment: You’re sorting the contents of the array, not one field in them. Sorting swaps the whole thing, otherwise the data would get all messed up.

Comment: @Gerhardh so i should remove the strcmp bit completely and then what do i do? Should i loop over each single `obj` struct in the sorted `objArray` and then do the whole strcmp thing?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ok that sounds logical. So i should just compare every obj with every other obj after the sorting has occured and see which ones are equal and then compare and swap their strings? Isn't there a better way to do that?

Comment: No, you should return `cmpResult` or `-cmpResult` depending on desired sort direction.

Comment: Why do you expect `"3 z" < "3 a"` but `"1 simple" < "1 this" < "1 text"`. You want descending `count` but ascending `word` or random order of `word` ?

Comment: @Gerhardh isn't `simple` > `this` > `text` ?

Comment: Your sample show expected output "simple, this, text". Sorted order would be "simple, text, this" in ascending order or "this, text, simple" in descending order. Pick one. But "simple, this, text" is camel case order or whatever you may call it. s<t and e<h when sorting

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry, i just had the whole string comparison wrong in my head. Does it just compare individual chars and when one is bigger or smaller than the other then it stops? I mean it doesn't check the length of the string or the rest of the chars right?

Comment: It does alphabetical comparison. See [man strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3p.html). As in any phone book: a < aaa < ab < b .... < zzzzzz. It stops at the first mismatch.

Comment: @Gerhardh checking it right now, thanks i just had the comparison wrong in my head. Thank you for the link and your time. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function is not supposed to manipulate the objects that are compared.
You shall only return a compare result:

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    obj *objA = (obj *)a;
    obj *objB = (obj *)b;

    int res = objA->count - objB->count;
    // negative value means A is less than B.

    if(res == 0)
    {
        res = strcmp(objA->word, objB->word);
        // negative value if A is less than B.
    }

    return res; // or -res for other sorting direction
}
```

There is also no need to copy the elements in your function when you can use the pointers to access them directly in the array.

Comment: running that (returning -res), produces the following output : `3 z
3 a
2 is
1 this
1 text
1 simple` and the `counts` are sorted correctly in descending order but the last 3 words are not right? (where count = 1 for `this`, `text` and `simple`